# Is using a global mutex a bad practice?

Tags: concurrency, synchronization, pthreads, global-variables

I have 4 threads in a program (besides the main thread) that do some file I/O. They all read/write to the same file, so I thought of declaring a mutex to synchronize them as a global variable outside of main to avoid having to pass the same mutex around to each thread's function. Is this considered bad practice and should I instead pass the mutex to the function that each thread executes?

Comment: The mutex effectively goes along with the file handle (descriptor, ostream, etc) that they all write to.  Does it make design sense for that handle to be a global: i.e. you will never want to have more than one file, and so forth?  If so, then having the mutex global doesn't make it any worse.  If not, then the mutex should be passed along with the handle.

Comment: But in general, apply the same analysis as you would when considering whether to make any other shared variable a global (for which the answer is usually no).  There isn't anything particularly special about mutexes in that regard.

Comment: TLDR: Use a global mutex to protect global data. More generally, the scope and extent of any mutex should be the same as the scope and extent of the data it protects. The deeper question is what Nate Eldredge asked: Is using a global _variable_ a bad practice? (e.g., https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/148108/200736)